# OpenNI Issue? Xiron OS got an event timeout! Process has died

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, ubuntu, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm am attempting to get RGBDSLAM working on Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty).

I have used to following links to aid in installing ROS Electric, RGBDSLAM and openni_kinect:

- [ROS Electric](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu)
- [RGBDSLAM](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam)
- [openni_kinect](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect) - Using section 3.1 Ubuntu Installation.

For the [RGBDSLAM link](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam) I stopped at section 4 (Usage). This is because the terminal command

`roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch`

lead to only the RGBDSLAM UI to appear; pressing space or enter didn't seem to cause anything to happen.

From here, I decided to test to make sure I could actually use the kinect through openni. I started to follow [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch) and used

`roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`

in terminal. The final timeout seems to occur sometimes as I use rviz.

```
... logging to /home/cleros/.ros/log/89f8eb9e-bf87-11e1-8df5-000c29684d60/roslaunch-ubuntu-10105.log
        Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
        Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
        Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
        
        started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:50032/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /camera/driver/rgb_frame_id
 * /camera/disparity_depth_registered/min_range
 * /camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url
 * /camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth/interpolation
 * /camera/driver/depth_frame_id
 * /camera/depth/rectify_depth/interpolation
 * /camera/disparity_depth/max_range
 * /rosversion
 * /camera/driver/device_id
 * /camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url
 * /camera/disparity_depth/min_range
 * /camera/disparity_depth_registered/max_range

NODES
  /camera/depth/
    rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    points (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/rgb/
    debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_mono (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
  /
    camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    camera_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
  /camera/
    driver (nodelet/nodelet)
    register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_depth_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/ir/
    rectify_ir (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/depth_registered/
    rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    metric (nodelet/nodelet)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [10123]
process[camera/driver-2]: started with pid [10124]
process[camera/rgb/debayer-3]: started with pid [10136]
process[camera/rgb/rectify_mono-4]: started with pid [10148]
process[camera/rgb/rectify_color-5]: started with pid [10161]
process[camera/ir/rectify_ir-6]: started with pid [10173]
process[camera/depth/rectify_depth-7]: started with pid [10195]
process[camera/depth/metric_rect-8]: started with pid [10214]
process[camera/depth/metric-9]: started with pid [10239]
process[camera/depth/points-10]: started with pid [10247]
process[camera/register_depth_rgb-11]: started with pid [10256]
process[camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth-12]: started with pid [10270]
process[camera/depth_registered/metric_rect-13]: started with pid [10295]
process[camera/depth_registered/metric-14]: started with pid [10308]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb-15]: started with pid [10321]
process[camera/disparity_depth-16]: started with pid [10337]
process[camera/disparity_depth_registered-17]: started with pid [10362]
process[camera_base_link-18]: started with pid [10367]
process[camera_base_link1-19]: started with pid [10368]
process[camera_base_link2-20]: started with pid [10387]
process[camera_base_link3-21]: started with pid [10388]
[ERROR] [1340712730.404773751]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1340712730.409808584]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]
[ INFO] [1340712732.747229754]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1340712732.747448067]: 1. device on bus 001:10 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00365902215039A'
[ INFO] [1340712732.748565581]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1340712732.789789267]: Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 1:10 with serial number 'A00365902215039A'
[ INFO] [1340712732.822360542]: rgb_frame_id = '/camera_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1340712732.822507419]: depth_frame_id = '/camera_depth_optical_frame' 
[ WARN] [1340712732.829450520]: Camera calibration file /home/cleros/.ros/camera_info/rgb_A00365902215039A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1340712732.831062365]: Camera calibration file /home/cleros/.ros/camera_info/depth_A00365902215039A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1340712732.832879334]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1340712732.833297957]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
  what():  virtual void openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::startDepthStream() @ /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-openni-kinect-0.3.4/debian/ros-electric-openni-kinect/opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_camera/src/openni_device.cpp @ 257 : starting depth stream failed. Reason: Xiron OS got an event timeout!
  [camera_nodelet_manager-1] process has died [pid 10123, exit code -6].
    log files: /home/cleros/.ros/log/89f8eb9e-bf87-11e1-8df5-000c29684d60/camera_nodelet_manager-1*.log
```

Any suggestions to getting openni/kinect working would be much appreciated!

I've been trying to get this going for the last few hours now with no success!

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37303/openni-issue?-xiron-os-got-an-event-timeout!-process-has-died./) by [cleros](https://answers.ros.org/users/2716/cleros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2012-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cleros](https://answers.ros.org/users/2716/cleros/) on 2012-06-26**:
@nitasgu: According to http://ros.org/wiki/roscore roslaunch automatically starts roscore if roscore isn't going. I'm not sure how to restart roscore (I'm new to ROS) - however I would have assumed several restarts of Ubuntu should have done a restart of roscore?

**Comment by [cleros](https://answers.ros.org/users/2716/cleros/) on 2012-06-30**:
@Felix Endres: I'm running Ubuntu in VMWare so that may explain the issue. Unfortunately, I don't really have the time at the moment to check to confirm this is the case. Thanks.

EDIT: Appears VMWare was the issue in the end. Thanks again Felix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many people having similar problems. I could always get things to work by switching to another usb socket. The driver doesn't work with usb 3 and also not in a virtual machine. Also note that openni_camera (as started by kinect+rgbdslam.launch) and openni_launch may differ and interfer.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1